# Posting data from form and validating data using django detailview

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-generic-views

I am working in django 1.8 project, and I have a model called company and I have used the generic view to do simple CRUD over this model.

I have a detail view, which renders the detail of the `company model` in a template name called `company/company_detail.html`

The detail page is rendered with the `company` object information. Along with the company object info, I have added a form in this detail page, and I want to process the form data with this `DetailView` method. I tried to use the post method of `CompanyDetailView` but, it doesn't work, when I try to navigate the CompanyDetailView page, the post method executed automatically which I don't want, What I want is execute the `post` method of `CompanyDetailView` when the post request came to this `CompanyDetailView` class.

Here is the `CompanyDetailView`

```
class CompanyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/company_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'company'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       price_value = request.POST.get('paid-value')
       print(price_value)
       return render(request, 'company/company_detail.html', {'company':self.context_object_name}
```

## The `company_detail.html` is

```
<body>
 {% block main %}
   {{company.name}} 
  <form method="post" action=""> 
   Paid Value: <input type="number" name="paid-value", required>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="pay">
  </form>
 {% endblock main %}
</body>
```

## urls.py file

```
url(r'company/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CompanyDetailView.as_view(), name="company"),
```

Comment: "When I try to navigate the CompanyDetailView page, the post method executed automatically." Are you sure? I don't see how that would be possible. More generally though it probably isn't a good idea to POST to the same view - use a separate `FormView` instead that redirects back to the detail view after posting.

Comment: @solarissmoke I am sure, the post method executed automatically, When I call the url of detail view. yes, I can create another function based view and map to a URL, but I don't want to make another complication, by setting another view and modelForm.